# Why is Ghidra appending a memory address to a string that is displayed instead of a variable?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, ghidra

This is my first time using Ghidra and debugging. My project deals with reverse engineering a Dos executable from 2007, to understand how it generates a code.

I looked for the strings I can read when launching the program through wine (debugging under linux) and found one place :

```
                    /* Reverses the string */
                __strrev(local_8);
                local_4 = 0;
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE(s__Code_=_%s_0040704c);
```

with `DISPLAY_MESSAGE` being :

```
int __cdecl DISPLAY_MESSAGE(byte *param_1)

{
  int iVar1;
  int errorCode;

  iVar1 = FUN_004019c0((undefined4 *)&DAT_004072e8);
  errorCode = FUN_00401ac0((char **)&DAT_004072e8,param_1,(undefined4 *)&stack0x00000008);
  FUN_00401a60(iVar1,(int *)&DAT_004072e8);
  return errorCode;
}
```

I named the function "DISPLAY_MESSAGE" because I saw the string on the screen ;-). I would like to name it `printf` but its signature does not match the one of `printf` since it takes `byte *` instead of `char *, ...` as input parameters and returns an `int` instead of `void` for the actual `printf`.

The string "Code    = %s" (stripping the CRs and new lines) is actually located at address "0040704c", and I am very surprised not to see the variable holding the generated code value instead (that could help me rename the variables).

If I change the signature to the one of `printf` it yields :

```
DISPLAY_MESSAGE(s__Code_=_%s_0040704c,local_8)
```

which looks better, because `local_8` could be the code, but I don't know if it is correct to change the signature like this (since then the local variable that I renamed `errorCode` is never used whereas it was returned before signature change).

```
void __cdecl DISPLAY_MESSAGE(char *param_1,...)

{
  int iVar1;
  int errorCode;

  iVar1 = FUN_004019c0((undefined4 *)&DAT_004072e8);
  FUN_00401ac0((char **)&DAT_004072e8,(byte *)param_1,(undefined4 *)&stack0x00000008);
  FUN_00401a60(iVar1,(int *)&DAT_004072e8);
  return;
}
```

So my questions are :

1. Why is Ghidra appending `_0040704c` to the string (should it help me, and how should I make use of this piece of info) ?
2. If my signature change is correct, what prevents Ghidra from finding the correct signature from its analysis ?
3. Should I think there is a problem with the function signature whenever I see `undefinedX` as it appears in `DISPLAY_MESSAGE` ?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `0040704c` is definitely the static address where the function is present.

Comment: @R4444 thanks. Is it of any help while reverse-engineering a program ?